# JS: parse dynamically added script before other scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have the following on my page:

1. a script ("script1.js") that adds a second script ("script2.js") dynamically to the page.
2. a third script ("script3.js").

"script3" overwrites some of the functions in "script2", therefore the order that the scripts should be parsed is:

script1 > script2 > script3.

And the console should show: 1 2 3. Instead I see 1 3 2.

I have tried using "defer" on "script3" with no success:

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script defer type='text/javascript' src="script3.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

script1.js:

```
console.log('1');
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const url = 'script2.js';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
head.appendChild(script);
```

script2.js:

```
console.log('2');
```

script3.js:

```
console.log('3');
```

Comment: If that's the exact code in script1, you could just include that as a script tag but I guess that's not an option here. A workaround would be to also dynamically load the third script, but depending on the amount of scripts that should be loaded after the second might make this unviable

Comment: Your workarounds do indeed work, but I would like the third script to be fixed in the HTML and the second to be loaded dynamically.

Comment: did you look at jQuery.getScript() or something like that where you can chain load the scripts? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: jQuery is one of the scripts that is to be loaded dynamically. So solution has to be vanilla js/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ugly as it sounds, you could use `document.write` inside `script1.js` to load `script2.js`. The scripts will execute in correct order.

```
// script1.js
console.log('1');
document.write('<script src="script2.js"></script>');
```

Comment: Works like a charm, can't believe I didn't try this before. I saw this mentioned on various other questions, but somehow overlooked it (security is not an issue in my case). Thanks!